# Formatting text in posts

Tags: formatting

In a post on WordPress, is there a way of selecting items of text and applying formatting, such as font / font style and font size?

I see that there is a 'Format' dropdown... should I change the styles of the items here first? And if so, how is this done?

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1):

Find the Kitchen Sink button on the visual editor you should find Lots of options for formatting text:

[image: Kitchen Sink Button]

Comment: I clicked that, but I don't see how to change these things with the new buttons that appear from kitchen sink

Comment: just select the texts you want to to change formatting then just click on any of the formatting options.

Comment: But how do I change text to formatting that isn't aligned with all the properties in any single item in the Paragraph dropdown? For example, if I only want to increase the size of the font, how do I do that? And how do I change the font to a serif style?